# Outlook 2007 Customization Files when on an Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, windows-vista, outlook-2007, microsoft-office

long time no see.

I've searched the Internet high and low with no luck. I think I actually found the end of the internet and needed an 8in floppy to get in and a punch card to get out, but, none the less.

Here's the scenario

SBS 2003 with 20 clients, mixed Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP Pro SP3
All machines have Office 2007
I Migrated them to SBS 2011, Client machines stayed the same.

The Migration went flawlessly, the only issue on 19 of the machines is the fact that they lost their outlook email address history, so when you open a new email and type the address in the To: field, the history is gone. Annoyance but they'll survive.

One machine, a Vista machine had a highly customized Outlook with Marco's, Scripts, Rules, Custom Toolbar, ETC!

None of the customizations went over with the migration.

My Migration process is simple enough, export outlook to PST
Run Windows Files and settings transfer wizard, Backup any data that is not saved to server, stuff on desktop, ETC.

Remove from old Domain.
Down old Server
Boot up new server
Add PC's to new domain
Run file and settings transfer wizard
Import PST.

This has been my process for years and always works quite well, except this one machine.

I've found many articles out on the net for copying settings like outcmd.dat to get a toolbar back from an old outlook that is/was using a pop server.
I tried copying this file just to test and it does not get her toolbar back.

I'm going to do a system restore from before the migration to see if I can get it back up with the old settings but, in the end the question is, Are there custom setting files I am missing that would hold all these settings that are different from pop/smtp versus exchange. and whether they are different or not, do you guys know the names of them so I can copy them to a USB stick or some such and paste them into the new profile I create.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete file is called an NK2 file.

See here:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/copy-autocomplete-name-list-to-another-computer-HA001139451.aspx for examples (albeit older version but still applies)

BTW, a great tool for migration user profiles, etc. when you do things like you did is called ProfWiz = http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html  I use it all the time...works like a champ and is very cheap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [User State Migration Tool 4.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560792%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_2) to migrate settings between machines (or on the same machine during an OS upgrade). USMT 4.0 is capable of migrating settings from older to newer versions of Office.

> USMT 4.0 does not migrate the following application settings:
>
> ```
> Settings from earlier versions of an application. 
> The versions of each application must match on the source and 
> destination computers.
> ```
>
> This is because USMT does not support migrating the settings of an
>   earlier version of an application to a later version, **except for
>   Microsoft Office, which USMT can migrate from an earlier version to a
>   later version.**

Answer (score 0):

These don't really help me with the current situation as they are meant to be done before or during the migration, not after its to late. LOL

Thank you both though. Upvoted both replies

What I ended up doing was logging in as the Domain admin, copying the old profile over top of the new one, fixing permissions and crossing my fingers.

It still didn't work which truthfully doesn't surprise me.

Again, thanks for the useful links. ;)